# LINQ Left Outer Join not working (with example)

Tags: c#, linq

I have left outer join that works correctly in Oracle, but fails to work when converted into LINQ. When executed through LINQ I get no records since for the user searched the record does not exist in T_PER_ADDL_ATRB

**SQL**

```
SELECT  P.*
FROM    T_PER P
        INNER  JOIN T_PER_CMN_ATRB C ON C.PER_ID = P.PER_ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN T_PER_ADDL_ATRB A22 ON A22.PER_CMN_ATRB_ID = C.PER_CMN_ATRB_ID
WHERE   A22.ADDL_ATRB_ID = 22
        AND (C.PER_LST_NM LIKE 'Chen%' or A22.ADDL_ATRB_VAL like 'Chen%');
```

SQL returns 1 record

**LINQ**

```
(from P in db.T_PER
join C in db.T_PER_CMN_ATRB on P.PER_ID equals C.PER_ID
join A22 in db.T_PER_ADDL_ATRB on C.PER_CMN_ATRB_ID equals A22.PER_CMN_ATRB_ID into A22_join
from A22 in A22_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
  A22.ADDL_ATRB_ID == 22 &&
  (C.PER_LST_NM.StartsWith("Chen") ||
  A22.ADDL_ATRB_VAL.StartsWith("Chen"))
select P).ToList()
```

LINQ returns 0 records

Comment: As soon as Oracle is not doing something special to convert your SQL, `WHERE   A22.ADDL_ATRB_ID = 22` basically should kill the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Try adding that condition before joining, e.g. `join A22 in db.T_PER_ADDL_ATRB.Where(A22 => A22.ADDL_ATRB_ID == 22)` and remove it from `Where` clause.

Comment: Your SQL is searching on Chen, but your Linq is using Konyayev.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> LeftJoin<TSource, TInner, TKey, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,                                                 IEnumerable<TInner> inner, Func<TSource, TKey> pk, Func<TInner, TKey> fk, Func<TSource, TInner, TResult> result)
    {
        IEnumerable<TResult> _result = Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();

        _result = from s in source
                  join i in inner
                  on pk(s) equals fk(i) into joinData
                  from left in joinData.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select result(s, left);

        return _result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Where` with `DefaultIfEmpty()` so the condition would be added in `LEFT OUTER JOIN` clause

```
(from P in db.T_PER
join C in db.T_PER_CMN_ATRB on P.PER_ID equals C.PER_ID
join A22 in db.T_PER_ADDL_ATRB on C.PER_CMN_ATRB_ID equals A22.PER_CMN_ATRB_ID into A22_join
from A22 in A22_join.Where(x => x.ADDL_ATRB_ID == 22).DefaultIfEmpty()
where 
  (C.PER_LST_NM.StartsWith("Konyayev") ||
    (A22 == null || (A22 != null && A22.ADDL_ATRB_VAL.StartsWith("Konyayev"))
    )
  )
select P).ToList()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could something similar to the below:

```
from p in db.TPER
join c in db.T_PER_CMN_ATRB on p.PER_ID equals c.PER_ID
join a22 in db.T_PER_ADDL_ATRB.Where(p=> p.ADDL_ATRB_ID == 22) on c.PER_ID equals a22.PER_CMN_ATRB_ID into a22_join
from a22table in a22_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {
a22table.ADDL_ATRB_ID,
C.PER_LST_NM,
A22.ADDL_ATRB_VAL
P,
}).Where(p=> p.PER_LST_NM.StartsWith("Chen") || p.ADDL_ATRB_VAL.StartsWith("Chen")).ToList()
```

Comment: This works but performance is terrible. I am guessing because 2 statements are done instead of one.